# Python - why doesn't this simple regex work?

Tags: python, regex

This code below should be self explanatory. The regular expression is simple.  Why doesn't it match?

```
>>> import re
>>> digit_regex = re.compile('\d')
>>> string = 'this is a string with a 4 digit in it'
>>> result = digit_regex.match(string)
>>> print result
None
```

Alternatively, this works:

```
>>> char_regex = re.compile('\w')
>>> result = char_regex.match(string)
>>> print result
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10044e780>
```

Why does the second regex work, but not the first?

Comment: because `match` matches only at the beginning of the string, use `search` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second finds a match because `string` starts with a word character. If you want to find matches within the string, use the `search` or `findall` methods (I see this was suggested in a comment too). Or change your regex (e.g. `.*(\d).*`) and use the .groups() method on the result.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) is what `re.match()` says `If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern ...`

In your case the string doesn't have any digit `\d` at the beginning. But for the `\w` it has `t` at the beginning at your string.

If you want to check for digit in your string using same mechanism, then add `.*` with your regex:

```
digit_regex = re.compile('.*\d')
```

Comment: This is quite improper compared to simply using the re.search() method or one of the find*() methods. See here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects

Comment: @GrahamR.Armstrong you are right. I am just explaining the `match()` here and why it didn't work for OP.

Comment: Alright, fair enough, still I would personally append that information to give a more complete answer.